# AttributeError: module 'dill' has no attribute '_dill' when importing datasets

Tags: python, dill, huggingface-datasets

In Python 3.9.13, when importing the package datasets, I get an AttributeError from the dill package.

I am running the following versions :
datasets : 2.9.0
dill : 0.3.6

Is there any specific modification of the packages needed ?
Thank you for your help

From :
`import datasets`

i get :

````
    import datasets

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\datasets\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    from .arrow_dataset import Dataset

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\datasets\arrow_dataset.py", line 66, in <module>
    from .arrow_writer import ArrowWriter, OptimizedTypedSequence

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\datasets\arrow_writer.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .features import Features, Image, Value

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\datasets\features\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .audio import Audio

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\datasets\features\audio.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ..download.streaming_download_manager import xopen

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\datasets\download\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .download_manager import DownloadManager, DownloadMode

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\datasets\download\download_manager.py", line 36, in <module>
    from ..utils.py_utils import NestedDataStructure, map_nested, size_str

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\datasets\utils\py_utils.py", line 602, in <module>
    class Pickler(dill.Pickler):

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\datasets\utils\py_utils.py", line 605, in Pickler
    dispatch = dill._dill.MetaCatchingDict(dill.Pickler.dispatch.copy())

AttributeError: module 'dill' has no attribute '_dill'```
````

Comment: What have you saved your main script file as?

Comment: Hi, it is a .py script.

Comment: a .py script... named...?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get that you needed the fll name : it's "fine_tuning_Bert.py".

Comment: OK. That rules out one possible cause of the problem (if you name the script you're working on `dill.py` it's trying to import that module when you do `import dill`, and nothing you expect to be in there will be there). But that's not the problem.